MariaDB Docker image: How to get meaningful log levels (everything is logged as error)?
I'm using the MariaDB docker image with podman for a Nextcloud instance. Everything works, but when I look at the logs (with podman logs or journalctl), everything is logged at log level error. It seems to me that the container just writes everything to stderr which journald on the host then picks up at the level error, even though the messages themselves are mostly harmless such as:
2024-04-22 21:46:51 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.11.7-MariaDB-1:10.11.7+maria~ubu2204-log source revision 87e13722a95af5d9378d990caf48cb6874439347 as process 1

How can I get the container to log at appropriate levels? E.g. by only sending actual errors to stderr but all informational messages or warnings to stdout?

see here how you can add your own nysqk.cnf file to docker https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47374644/docker-mysql-image-cant-change-my-cnf-file

There's no easy way currently. Important things will have [ERROR] in them. Rest can be ignored

Thanks, @nbk's answer seems to be right.
I have tried to change the configuration, especially around the log-warnings option, but that didn't reduce the log noise at all.
So, I ended up sticking with the default configuration and adding filters to my log monitoring instead. Not my preferred approach, but it works.
